# Accessing jQuery Variable on form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My data looks something like this

I have a parent class which has some attributes and list of child objects.

Child class has attributes like ID and Name.

What I want to achieve is

- On load display all the parent items.
- On click of a parent item list all the child items below.

I could achieve this using following jQuery function

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".parent").click(function () {
        $("#child").show();
        var v1 = "parent_" + $(this).attr('id');
        $("#" + v1).slideToggle("slow");
        $("#" + v1).siblings().hide();

    });
```

This function is performing well as far as hiding or displaying the div containing child items is concerned.

I have provided a button which helps me add new parent items.

Similarly I want to provide a button which will help me add a child item under selected parent item.

I'm not sure how to provide the parent id when the button in child item div is clicked.

Is there a way where I can create a variable in above mentioned function and use it on click of 'Add Child' button?

Comment: Is document.getElementById("Child") working ?

Comment: Post your html code as well..

Comment: Try if `$(this).parent()` can help? Or perhaps `$(this).closest(".parent")`.

Comment: Thanks this worked.. .

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$(this).parent()
```

or

```
$(this).closest(".parent")
```

and get id of parent and store your child of respective parent